# Variable does not exist twig symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a controller that does this

```
  /**
 * @Route("/AjaxAddQuestionForm/{section}")
 * @ParamConverter("section", class="AppBundle:Section")
 */
public function ajaxAddQuestionFormAction(Request $request, $section)
{
    $question = new Question();
    $addQuestionForm = $this->createForm(new AddQuestionType(), $question);

    return $this->render('AppBundle:Form:ajaxAddQuestionForm.html.twig', array(
      'section' => $section,
      'addAjaxQuestionForm' => $addQuestionForm->createView(),
  ));
}
```

The ajaxAddQuestionForm.html.twig file looks like this

```
{% embed 'modal.html.twig' %}
{% block labelledby %}addnewquestion{% endblock %}
{% block modalId %}addnewquestion{% endblock %}

{% block modalHead %}
{{ 'client.modal.head'| trans }}
{% endblock %}
{% block modalBody %}
{{form_start(addAjaxQuestionForm)}}

<div>
  {{form_widget(addAjaxQuestionForm.section, {value: section.id})}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  {{form_label(addAjaxQuestionForm.name, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'form-label'}}) }}
  <span class="help"></span>
  <div class="controls">
    {{form_widget(addAjaxQuestionForm.name, {'attr':{'class':'form-control'}})}}
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {{form_label(addAjaxQuestionForm.category, null, {'label_attr': {'class': 'form-label'}}) }}
  <span class="help"></span>
  <div class="controls">
    {{form_widget(addAjaxQuestionForm.category, {'attr':{'width':'100%'}})}}
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block modalFooter %}
<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">{{'client.form.cancel'| trans}}</button>
<input class="btn btn-primary create" type="submit" value="{{'client.form.add.client'| trans}}">
{{form_end(addAjaxQuestionForm)}}
{% endblock %}
{% endembed %}
```

And finally I have an edit.html.twig that looks like this

```
 <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="{% block labelledby %}{% endblock %}" class="modal fade" id="{% block modalId %}{% endblock %}" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">

      <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{% block modalHead %}{% endblock %}</h4>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      {% block modalBody %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      {% block modalFooter %}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

{% include 'AppBundle:Form:ajaxAddQuestionForm.html.twig' %}
```

Now I get the following error:

```
Variable "addAjaxQuestionForm" does not exist in src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Form/ajaxAddQuestionForm.html.twig at line 9
```

Any idea what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

In your *edit.html.twig* (assuming your `addAjaxQuestionForm` variable exists in it), you need to pass it on to the included twig.

```
{% include 'AppBundle:Form:ajaxAddQuestionForm.html.twig' with {'addAjaxQuestionForm': addAjaxQuestionForm} %}
```

Comment: I have had to do this when I'm including another twig inside a block

Comment: Problem is that the variable does not exist in edit as it is returned to ajaxAddQuestionForm.html.twig

Comment: it seems like there is something else wrong, if i where you, i would try to simplify your templates, taking out the embeds and other blocks, to where you only render your form, then start re-building all the stuff around it, seeing where at wich point fails ...

Comment: Seems like good advise. I think there is a much cleaner way of doing things than the way I'm doing them now. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Section:ajaxAddQuestionFormAction',{'section':section})) }}
```

Instead of Include and you must add "section" parameter to ajaxAddQuestionFormAction.

We can help you more than that if you don't publish us all the code that concern the part of your problem.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should use render controller method instead of include

```
{{ render(controller(
        'AppBundle:Form:ajaxAddQuestionForm',
        { 'section': section }
    )) }}
```

read more about it here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers